# React Native - iOS Release Builds taking time after enabling Hermes

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-devops, react-native-hermes

I have a React Native Project created using the CLI. I enabled Hermes Engine for both Android and iOS.

#### When building the app on Azure DevOps CI:

- Before Hermes: it took ~26 minutes
- After Hermes: its taking more than ~45 mins

I have tried googling for the impact of enabling Hermes engine on iOS Builds but couldn't really find a good answer.

Just want to understand if this is normal (because it sure doesn't look normal to me).

Answer (score 1):

So turns out that the app does gets built but there definitely is an increase in the build time. For the time being, we have decided not to enable Hermes on iOS side. The reasoning behind this was that React Native is already performant on iOS compared to Android.

Comment: Agree with you, iOS is already faster with JSC.